# How to crop an object in Inkscape and update the object's node paths to reflect the new shape?

Tags: inkscape, path, crop, path-effects

I created a circle in Inkscape that I want to crop a smaller circle out of, and then use the Corners (Fillet/Chamfer) Path Effect to round the edges of the cropped out area, creating the shape of a painter's palette.

After cropping out a rectangle and smaller circle from the bigger circle, I have a C-like shape ready for filleting. However, the node paths (the green diamonds) only exist for the original big circle. How do I crop the original object into a new shape in a way that's reflected in the node paths?

[image: four node paths for circle]

Answer (score 1):

The Corners (Fillet/Chamfer) LPE won't work on a shape created with an object created using the Power Clip LPE, because the result of the Power Clip is not an actual vector, it's only a path effect applied to a clipped object.  Also it can't be converted to an ordinary path either, because it's made using a clip. You'll need to use Inskcape's ordinary boolean operations to create the shape.

Do it like this instead

1. Create a circle and a rectangle the same height
2. Using snapping, move the rectangle over the circle, select both shapes and do *Path > Union*
3. Draw a larger circle, and place the new shape you made in the previous steps on top of the larger circle (*Object > Raise to top*). Change the fill colour so you can see it.
4. Select both shapes and do *Path > Difference*
5. Now the Corners (Fillet/Chamfer) LPE will work

[image]